# Recuperar valor de un array

Tags: php, array

Buen día, estoy haciendo una función que recupera una fecha que está dentro de un array, pero no logro obtenerla, la función es la siguiente:

```
 public function getProximoPago()
    {
        $recibo_pago = $this->entity->getJSONOperacion($this->id_caja_operacion);
        $datos_ticket = json_decode($recibo_pago['datos_ticket']);

        return mb_strtoupper($datos_ticket->pagos[4]);
    }
```

La variable datos_ticker ya recibe el array con toda la información, el cual es:

```
{
    "nombre_empresa": ,
    "fecha_operacion": "20/02/2020",
    "hora_operacion": "13:06:39",
    "fecha_valor": "2020-02-20",
    "pagos": [{
        "id_credito": 120,
        "dirigido": "Credito",
        "saldo_vencido": 766,
        "saldo_proxima_cuota": "1350.00",
        "fecha_proxima_cuota": "2020-01-31",
        "capital": 1,
        "interes": 0,
        "otros": 0,
        "iva": 0
    }]
}
```

Yo quiero imprimir fecha_proxima_cuota que se encuentra dentro de pagos.

agradecería mucho su ayuda

Comment: Intenta con `return mb_strtoupper($datos_ticket->pagos[0]->fecha_proxima_cuota);`

Comment: @alanfcm, muchas gracias, si me funcionó.

Comment: @alanfcm sugiero que escribas una respuesta explicando un poco por qué funciona así (OP creía que el dato estaba en la posición 4, pero `pagos` es una array con un objeto JSON dentro).  Juan Pablo, me pregunto por qué usas `mb_strtoupper` para obtener una fecha ¿?

Answer (score 0):

La variable `pagos` es un array con un objeto JSON dentro.  Como hay un solo objeto en el array, puedes accesar el primer indice, o sea 0, y luego accesas la propiedad que quieres.  Quedaria asi:

```
return mb_strtoupper($datos_ticket->pagos[0]->fecha_proxima_cuota);
```